# What mistake I'm making in .htaccess file for my folder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, error-log

I'm using HTTP Apache webserver and PHP.

I've a folder called **"rest"** inside **"www"** folder in which I've created one .htaccess file and written following code into it.

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
Options + FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Request routing 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]*)$ index.php?name=$1 [nc, qsa]
```

Then I run the index.php file from this folder in a browser then I got following error in a browser.

```
**Internal Server Error**
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

After that I checked the apache error log in a file `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. I found following line there :

```
[Sat Jan 17 13:02:13.470123 2015] [core:alert] [pid 1297] [client 127.0.0.1:42956] /var/www/rest/.htaccess: Illegal option
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error here: `[nc, qsa]` (spaces in between).

You can use:

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
Options + FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Request routing, skip directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)$ index.php?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Turn on the rewrite engine

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

## Request routing

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]*)$   index.php?name=$1 [nc,qsa]